# After unpublishing an app on Google Play, will users still be able to buy inapps?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

After unpublishing an app on Google Play, will existing users still be able to buy inapps?

Does anyone have any official statement on this matter?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong since I have never tried it but I believe they can as long as they have the apk. however you can `Deactivate` the product in your products list then they should not be able to buy it

Answer (score 0):

No, users will not be able to make IAP:

> "To be visible to a user during checkout, an item's publishing state
>   must be set to Published and the item's application must be published
>   on Google Play."

quoted from [Administering In-app Billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html)