# Unpublishing a Google Play app and IAP

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

So I have this app in the Google Play store. I have to unpublish the app, but there are users that have already made in-app purchases. Will unpublishing the app prevent any future purchases from being made by people who already have the app installed?

From what I can see, if a user will still be able to update the app even if it's unpublished: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en

"When you unpublish an app, existing users can still use your app and receive app updates. Your app won’t be available for new users to find and download on Google Play."

However, IAP seem to inherit the publish/unpublish state from their parent app: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1072599?hl=en

"**Unpublished state is inherited from the parent application.** If the parent application for an in-app product is ever unpublished, the in-app products for the application are also considered unpublished even if the in-app product’s state is published."

And unpublished products can't be purchased, right? So does this mean that all users who have the game installed will have purchasing break immediately if I take down the app?

If so, are there any other solutions I'm missing here that would prevent users from searching/installing the app, but still be able to make purchases if they have the app installed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you already answered your question. Anyway, not a programming question.

Comment: I'm not sure if I answered my own question, because everything about the user experiance feels backwards and wrong. Continued to dig around more, and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27231941/after-unpublishing-an-app-on-google-play-will-users-still-be-able-to-buy-inapps?rq=1, but that question doesn't have a concrete answer.

Is there another stack exchange that would be better for this question?

Comment: Here is where your answer lies: `"Unpublished state is inherited from the parent application. If the parent application for an in-app product is ever unpublished, the in-app products for the application are also considered unpublished even if the in-app product’s state is published."`

Comment: In fact, just tested it -- indeed that behavior is what actually happens: **purchases can't be made the moment you unpublish** I still think it's backwards and wrong, but I guess what I really needed was some confirmation that I wasn't doing my work wrong. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

See above comments for more details: *No, payments don't work when you unpublish.*

However, update do, though forced updates don't seem to. If you need to get people off the old version for whatever reason, consider starting off with a server-side lever for payments, and lever payments off when you take down the app. You can use a message to get them to update when they try to make an IAP -- much better than just getting an Error from Google Play -- it doesn't seem to be workaround-able.